# Why is `wstring_convert` throwing a range_error?

Tags: c++, linux, utf-8, archlinux, codecvt

I have C++ code which converts `string` that contains ([ALCHEMICAL SYMBOL FOR AQUA REGIA](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%9F%9C%86)) to `u16string`:

```
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
    string s = "";

    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> converter;
    u16string s16 = converter.from_bytes(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Note, that I **don't** use `wstring` or any `istream`.

This gives me `std::range_error`:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::range_error'
  what():  wstring_convert::from_bytes
```

But [on ideone this code runs without error](https://ideone.com/dZPEW4).

I receive error with both g++ 7.2.0 and clang 4.0.1, when compiling with `-std=c++14`.

Why there is no error on ideone and why I receive this error?

---

I have arch linux 4.12.13 and `locale` command gives me:

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
...
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Did you really intend to convert a character that looks like a hollow square? Because I see a hollow square character.

Comment: @n.m. sorry, i add details about this character

Comment: Using non-base-charset characters in the source code is fragile. Nobody knows what your editor or compiler will do. A portable way to specify extended characters is via their universal character names.

Comment: @n.m. you are right, in real code i receive text containing this character from server. Here this character is inside code because of simplicity

Comment: Get rid of `setlocale()` (it doesn't apply in this code), and use `string s = u8"";` to ensure `s` is properly UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this what your converter should be like?

`std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> converter;`

Comment: This fixes my problem. Thanks a lot!